# Getting Integrity & NotNull errors for null value in DateField column when null and blank attributes have been set to True

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm currently using a Django backend, with a React/Redux frontend. When I try to add a new "Day" to my database, I get:

```
psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation: null value in column "day_date" ... violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2, null, Tu).

django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "day_date" ... violates not-null constraint
DETAIL: Failing row contains (2, null, Tu).
```

This shouldn't be an issue because in my model, `day_date` is a DateField:

```
class Day(models.Model):
    day_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    day_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    day_str = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_constraints = {
            'CHK_DayNotNull': 'CHECK (day_date IS NOT NULL OR day_str <> "")'
        }
```

I thought maybe it was an error with my constraint, but when I deleted the constraint I get the same error. I tried playing with the inputs of the `day_date` field in the model; I tried all the combinations and get the same error which makes me think something is wrong with how my database is being updated. I'm using PostgreSQL for my database.

I tried clearing cache. deleting all my migrations, and then running,

```
python3 manage.py flush
python3 manage.py makemigrations
python3 manage.py migrate
```

but I'm still getting the exact same error.

Comment: It has a `db_constraints` that checks that `day_date IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: `day_date IS NOT NULL OR day_str <> ""`, and in my example `day_str = 'Tu'`